# c# order a List<Dictionary<string,object>>

Tags: c#, extension-methods

how to order a  `List<Dictionary<String,object>>` the object contains only string

the dictionary is structured as below

```
[name: mario]
[surname: rossi]
[address: xxxxxx]
[age: 40]
```

i'd like to order the list of these dictionaries by "age"
may you help me please?

i've tried with:

```
myList.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y=>y.Value))
```

it gives me this error: the value isn't a string(ok i aggree with him, it's an object, i've to cast in some way)
but more important is that i can't tell to the "orderby" methods that it must order by age

Comment: Why do you have a `List<Dictionary<String,object>>`? Can you not change that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the dictionary contains 4 items? Or is it that each item has these 4 properties?

Comment: You can order each dictionary by age, Doesn't make sense to order the list by it though unless each dictionary only contains objects with the same age?

Comment: @Tony you can't order the *contents* of a dictionary (a dictionary is unordered), and ordering the dictionaries themselves **is** ordering the list; why can't you order the list?

Comment: @MarcGravell It would appear that I put in different interpretation on the question. I read it as each object having those four properties, not each dictionary having those four keys. Lets hope my intepretation as wrong for all the boys who've amassed some points off this...

Answer (score 6):

You want something along the lines of

```
var sorted = myList.OrderBy(dict => Convert.ToInt32(dict["age"]));
```

I 've used `Convert.ToInt32` defensively because there's a small chance you are using another data type for the age, and casting (unboxing) to the wrong type would throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

```
myList.Sort((x,y) => ((int)x["age"]).CompareTo((int)y["age"]));
```

or similar:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => Comparer.Default.Compare(x["age"], y["age"]));
```

However! It would be much easier if you used a proper type instead of the dictionary; then it would just be:

```
myList.Sort((x,y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));
```